# chrome mobile's download website doesn't download JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

Google Chrome mobile browser (e. g. version 57.0) has a download page feature, which lets you save a complete web page for later reading (details see https://blog.google/products/chrome/chrome-on-android-do-more-on-every/ under "A new downloads experience").

**Problem**

It seems that ALL JavaScript code is removed when you download the page. If you for example consider this bootstrap carousel example:
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/
You can go backwards and forward as long as you're viewing the page online. But if you save the page for offline use, all javascript code is removed and so the carousel isn't working anymore.

**My Questions**

- Is this a known limitation?
- If yes, why?
- Is there any documentation about that feature and any planned work on it?